# How to get the source route in the dead Letter channel?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I define a DeadLetterChannel. There I change some Values and save the MessageHistory into the exchange. Now I want to insert into the Headers from the exchange the Name of the Route where the exception happend. But I don't find any way to get the name of the source route.

Did anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the route id from the exchange property with the key `Exchange.FAILURE_ROUTE_ID`

```
String routeId = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.FAILURE_ROUTE_ID);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get there the name of the errorQueue not the name, where the error happends. Example: exception happend in queue "test1", the message recived the deadletterForRoutes. With your code I get "deadletterForRoutes", not "test1"

Comment: Sorry, your right. I had look in the wrong field.